# Getting table Name from IObjectClass using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I'm using IRelationshipClass.DestinationClass to get an IObjectClass.  From here, I want to be able to get the table name, but can only access the AliasName.

Any ideas?

---

The IObjectClass can be cast to a IDataset, which has the Name property, which is not the same as AliasName.  I should say thanks to Kirk, as it was some code he posted elsewhere that pointed me in the right direction.

For reference,

```
((IDataset)relClass.DestinationClass).Name
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to cast it to IDataset, which has a Name property.